# Loop through to Import Multiple Excel Files and convert each workbook in a file to .dta

Tags: excel, for-loop, stata

I have a file that contains over a 60 excel workbook that I would like to convert each of them to .dta file in stata. I search the net but could not find a decent way of doing it over a loop. I have written a code that needs expert help. In a directory and want to create a loop to save them as .dta files. The code goes as follow

```
 forvalues i=1/60{

import excel "D:\Okay\""`i'.xlsx", sheet("Sheet1") firstrow clear
save "D:\Okay\""`i'.dta"

}
```

Comment: From your code it seems that you have 60 files, not 1 as clearly stated in "a file". I've not edited this.

Answer (score 1):

We can't try out your code because it's specific to your computer. Please study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting questions.

But it's evident that

```
\Okay\""`i'.xlsx"
```

is unlikely to help. As documented many times over -- e.g. [U] 18.3.10 within http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u18.pdf and http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0042 -- the backslash you want to use under Windows (it's best not to assume everyone recognises your OS) also has a role in Stata as an escape character.

That command would be better off ending

```
\Okay/`i'.xlsx"
```

and similar comments apply to the other command lines mentioning files: change the backward slash before a local macro reference to a forward slash, and remove the unnecessary double quotation marks.

In fact all this is totally avoidable. Consider

```
cd "D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\Okay" 
forvalues i=1/60 {
    import excel `i'.xlsx, sheet("Sheet1") firstrow
    save `i'.dta 
}
```

Once you `cd` to work within a directory or folder, you can keep file names to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There was plenty of errors I did over there; however, I believe I figured it out. This what you have to code in order to work

```
  forvalues date=1/57{


  import excel "D:/Rami Chehab/University Degrees & Courses/PhD in Labour Economics/Data/Data 2016/UNCTAD/Okay/`date'.xlsx", sheet("Sheet1") firstrow clear
  save "D:/Rami Chehab/University Degrees & Courses/PhD in Labour Economics/Data/Data 2016/UNCTAD/Okay/`date'.dta" 


  }
```